# How to use git blame -S <revs-file>

Tags: git, git-rev-list, git-blame

What is the format of the `revs-file` argument for `git blame -S`?

I have tried running it with the output of `git rev-list` as follows but the blame attributes every line to the `HEAD` commit.

`git blame -S <(git rev-list HEAD~50 HEAD) $file`

I have also tried running `<(git rev-list ... | tac)` to reverse the `revs-file` in case that was the issue but it seems to produce the same output.

The goal is to blame each line of `$file` to a commit between `HEAD~50` and `HEAD`, defaulting to `HEAD~50` if the same line is present in all commits.

Comment: `git rev-list HEAD~50 HEAD` outputs the same thing as `git rev-list HEAD`.  Did you intend to use `git rev-list HEAD~50..HEAD`?  If so, the two dots are critical here.

Answer (score 1):

<s>If every line is attributed to the latest commit, that implies that every line was in fact touched in the latest commit.</s>

Usually this sort of thing happens when someone changes every line ending from a single newline to a CR/LF pair, or vice versa.

Aha, the above would be true *without* `-S`, but what `-S` means, for `git blame`, is to insert *grafts* into the commit graph.

This is a special feature intended to work with cvsserver (according to the comments), but it does not work with the way you're using it.

The format is simply a series of `<commit-ID> <parent-ID> ...\n` lines.  Since, in this case, you want to start `git blame` at `HEAD` and stop it at `HEAD~50`, we can do this:

```
git rev-parse HEAD~50 | git blame -S /dev/stdin $file
```

The `git rev-parse` outputs the SHA-1 of commit `HEAD~50`, with no additional lines, which makes that commit have no parent commit(s), which makes `git blame` stop the history traversal at that point.

(The command you used to feed the `-S` input, `git rev-list HEAD~50 HEAD`, lists *every* commit reachable from `HEAD~50` *or* from `HEAD`, as just a single commit ID, omitting the parents.  This is the same as `git rev-list HEAD`, since `HEAD~50` is itself reachable from `HEAD`.  Because this listed every commit with no parent IDs, this made `git blame` treat each commit as a root commit.  It then started with the `HEAD` commit, tried to find its parents, considered `HEAD` to be a root commit, and stopped there—which made that commit responsible for every source line.  In other words, by listing the `HEAD` commit ID, you got `git blame` to stop there.  That's why we want to list, instead, `HEAD~50`.)

Comment: Everything is `\n` and I was able to get different results using `git blame $file | while read line; do grep "$(echo -n '^'; echo "$line" | sed -E 's/^\^?([a-f0-9]{7,8}).*$/\1/g')" <(git rev-list HEAD~50 HEAD) > /dev/null && echo "$line"; done`